# overloading inserters and strange output(for '20' and '020')

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

i was learning to overload '<<' in a very simple program,& during my study,i found the following surprising output of my program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class student
{

int age;

 public:
student(){}
student(int a){age=a;}

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,student o); 
};

 /*operator overloaded in this block*/
 ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,student o)
{ 
stream<<o.age;
return stream;
}

int main()
{
student ob1(20),ob2(020);   
cout<<ob1;   /*will yield 20(as desired)*/
cout<<"\n"<<ob2;     /*yielding 16(why so)*/
    _getch();
return 0;
 }
```

any explainations please

Comment: try with 0x20 as well. You'll be surprised.

Comment: HAHA.....ya i was...bt got the point nw

Comment: Pass student by const reference. Otherwise you are making a copy when you pass it into the function.  `ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,student **const&** o)`

Comment: Hope you got the answer. For better performance declare it as: 
`friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream,const student& o);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

0 is the octal prefix for C++ integer literals and 20 in octal is 16 in decimal.

To explain further: If a literal starts with 0 the rest of the number will be interpreted to be in octal representation. In your example 2*8^1 + 0 * 8^0.

The syntax for integer literals is given in §2.14.2 in the most recent standard draft.

Answer (score 5):

```
student ob1(20),ob2(020);
```

You have written 020 which in C and C++ is interpreted as an *octal* number (base 8) due to the zero at the start. So 020 has the value 16 in decimal.

Answer (score 3):

You will find the answer here:

[How does C Handle Integer Literals with Leading Zeros, and What About atoi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661369/how-does-c-handle-integer-literals-with-leading-zeros-and-what-about-atoi)

You prefixed the literal with a zero, which means treat the number as octal and 20oct is 16dec.

Answer (score 2):

`020` is 20 in *octal*, just as `0x20` is 20 in hex. Remove the preceding 0 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The leading 0 specifies that the it is an octal number (base 8) so 20 in octal is 16.

Answer (score 1):

It's interpereting the 020 as an octal.  2*8=16.  Try switching it to a 3, itll show 24 for 030. If you put 0x20 itll go to 32 as its doing hexadecimal. :)