# C++ int with preceding 0 changes entire value

Tags: c++, variables

I have this very strange problem where if I declare an int like so

```
int time = 0110;
```

and then display it to the console the value returned is `72`. However when I remove the 0 at the front so that `int time = 110;` the console then displays `110` like expected.

Two things I'd like to know, first of all why it does this with a preceding 0 at the start of the int and is there a way to stop it so that `0110` at least equals `110`?
Secondly is there any way to keep it so that `0110` returns `0110`?
If you take a crack guess at the variable name I'm trying to do operations with 24hr time, but at this point any time before 1000 is causing problems because of this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is 0 a decimal literal or an octal literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895522/is-0-a-decimal-literal-or-an-octal-literal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does C Handle Integer Literals with Leading Zeros, and What About atoi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661369/how-does-c-handle-integer-literals-with-leading-zeros-and-what-about-atoi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An integer literal that starts from 0 defines an octal integer literal. Now in C++ there are four categories of integer literals

```
integer-literal:
    decimal-literal integer-suffixopt
    octal-literal integer-suffixopt
    hexadecimal-literal integer-suffixopt
    binary-literal integer-suffixopt
```

And octal-integer literal is defined the following way

```
octal-literal:
    0 octal-literal
    opt octal-digit
```

That is it starts from 0.

Thus this octal integer literal

```
0110
```

corresponds to the following decimal number

```
8^2 + 8^1
```

that is equal to `72`.

You can be sure that 72 in octal representation is equivalent to 110 by running the following simple program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::oct << 72 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
110
```

Comment: How would I then save it as a variable?

Comment: @SteppingHat You can use a variable of any integral type that can accomodate this value.. The value of the variable will not depend on how the integer literal is written in the source code.

Answer (score 3):

It is because of **Integer Literals**. Placing a `0` before number means its a octal number. For binary it is `0b`, for hexadecimal it is `0x` or `0X`. You don't need to write any thing for decimal. See the code bellow.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int binary = 0b10;
    int octal=010;
    int decimal = 10;
    int hexa = 0x10;
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", octal, decimal, hexa, binary);
}
```

For more information visit [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is interpreting the leading zero as an octal number. The octal value of "110" is 72 in decimal.  There's no need for the leading zero if you're just storing an int value.

You're trying to store "time" as it appears on a clock.  That's actually more complicated than a simple int.  You could store the number of minutes since midnight instead.

Answer (score 1):

Zero at the start means the number is in octal. Without it is decimal.