# Why it causes an ERROR?

Tags: c++, c, literals

I have coded a simple program in C++ on CODEBLOCK. the program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 09;              //ERROR: Invalid digit 9 in octal constant
    cout << num << endl;

    num = 08;             //ERROR: Invalid digit 9 in octal constant
    cout << num << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

This code is same as the previous one. But i have changed value and wrote num=09 instead of 015.

I'm agree that if i initialize (int num = 015), it gives output in OCTAL that is 13.

But in the above program where i tried to initialize (int num = 09 and num = 08) it gives ERROR that you can see.

First of all, I wish to know why it generates an ERROR and how?

Second is what is the logic behind it?

Please give me logical reasons with suitable examples if any.

Comment: It makes it octal.

Comment: Come on guys, it's a legitimate question and possibly difficult to google for. At least mark it as a dupe instead of downvoting.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I googled "c++ zero in front of integer literal" and the answer was contained in the google preview of the first page result.

Comment: @JamesRoot: Unless you put in the word "literal" which you might not realize all the results are about zero-padding numbers for output.

Comment: @crashmstr Nice, you found the dupe I couldn't find somehow.

Comment: And a C answer: [How does C Handle Integer Literals with Leading Zeros, and What About atoi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661369/how-does-c-handle-integer-literals-with-leading-zeros-and-what-about-atoi)

Comment: Brother @AlexD I agree with you. But there is again another question if i remove 0 it gives 15 which is in decimal. RIGHT? Why ?

Comment: Because numbers are interpreted as decimal by default.

Comment: @JalalJanKhan: Because it's the leading zero that causes it to be interpreted as octal. Remove the leading zero, it's interpreted as decimal.

Comment: thank you brother @MattiVirkkunen. That is what i was thinking. THANKS ONCE AGAIN

Comment: @James Root Note: In C, at least, `015` is not a literal.  It is an integer constant.  C defines 2 types of literal: _string_ and _compound_ and  `015`  is neither.

Comment: Regarding the invalid digit, octal is base 8.  That means the valid digits are 0-7, just like valid binary digits are 0-1.  So the digits 8 and 9 are not valid octal digits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leading zeros cause integers to be interpreted as octal numbers in C/C++. 015 in octal is (1*8) + 5 = 13 in decimal.

Comment: Detail `0x9` has a leading `0` and is not octal.  Some extensions include `0b` as a binary prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Constants in 8-base are defined that way. 15<sub>8</sub> = 13<sub>10</sub>.